# How to create a JSON string which only contains the changed values?

Tags: java, json, optimization

I want to minimize the amount of JSON data transferred. Let's say I have a class with 100 key/value pairs and then I change one of these and want to transfer that change, and nothing but that change, not the 99 unchanged ones.

Is there a java lib for making such a patch or diff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compare the new values with the old values and then create the JSON. So a pseudocode is:

```
for each entry in old values
  find entry key in new values
  if new value != old value
    put this into list of modified entries
end for
convert modified entries to JSON
```

Really nothing complicated.

Comment: I'm using google-gson to create JSON now, so starting to generate JSON myself is not what I want. That's why I asked for a lib.

Comment: you don't have create JSON by yourself, that's why I put there the last line - use google-gson to convert the array of modified entries to JSON. Existing JSON libraries won't do what you want, they're only capable of creating JSON. What you send in is conververted.